# Deploy/Redistribute binaries compiled with ObjectBox Go

Tags: go, software-distribution, objectbox

I'm using ObjectBox Go to replace SQLite for my app, which is supposed to run on standard PC (Linux/Windows/macOS), mobile phone (Android and iOS devices) and Web Browser (via wasm).

We need to [install](https://golang.objectbox.io/install) object box's binary library on developer machine, but it is impossible to do so on customer's device. Is there a distributable version of a binary library of ObjectBox Go? Or should I have to include the `install.sh` in my install script or build my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For desktop systems you should be able to ship the ObjectBox shared library with your application, you can download the required versions from the [objectbox-c GitHub repository](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/releases). It should be stored next to the application binary.

I don't know how Go apps are packaged for Android and iOS, but you might be able to use the `objectbox-android` [Maven dependency](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.objectbox/objectbox-android/) for Android and the `ObjectBox` [pod on CocoaPods](https://swift.objectbox.io/install#adding-objectbox-db-to-your-project) for iOS.